# What is true chmod for WordPress?

Tags: customization

For all the folders and files.

Please give some explained answer.

Comment: What do you mean under _true_ ? Best? Required? Recommended?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All files should be writable only by your user account. So the correct permissions for files and directories are:

- Directories: 755
- Files: 644

You may want to secure some files:

- wp-config.php: for maximum security, this file should be made writable by your user only or its group. This means 400 or 440 permission
- .htaccess: 666 permission, so that WordPress can automatically generate rewrite rules for you
- wp-content/: some plugins and themes may require write access to this directory. you will be prompted when necessary.
- wp-content/themes/: 664 permission if you want to use the theme editor

References:

- [Changing File Permissions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions#Permission_Scheme_for_WordPress)
- [Hardening WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress#File_permissions)

Comment: That .htaccess permission looks menacing.